# Склоняется ли "Фэн Шуй"?

Tags: заимствования, ономастика, морфология

Можно ли сказать: "Обставить комнату по Фэн Шую"? Или в данном случае "Фэн Шуй" не склоняется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не склоняется.  Это подтверждено "Орфографическим словарем" под ред. В.В.Лопатина: **фэн-шуй**, нескл., м. и с. Кстати, с маленькой буквы и через дефис.

Comment: Нет, это слово пишется именно так: "Фэн Шуй", так что тут написано правильно. Я работаю в эзотерической газете 11 лет, общаюсь с "фэншуистами" мирового уровня. Уж они-то лучше знают, как правильно пишется название их науки, и доверяю их мнению больше, чем составителям орфографического словаря, которые вряд ли понимают, что это такое.

Comment: Я никоим образом не оспариваю Ваш комментарий. Может, Вы и правы. Но есть нормы русского языка, которым мы должны следовать, есть правила, которыми мы руководствуемся. Если бы мы все писали/говорили, как нам хочется или как между собой употребляет слово/выражение определенная группа специалистов (пускай даже с мировым именем!), то, наверное,  был бы языковой хаос, а не правильная речь. Спорить об это можно, но, я думаю, не нужно. Может, когда-то нормативным и будет Ваш вариант, но на данный момент рекомендовано такое написание.

Comment: Есть еще женьшень, тоже полезная штука) И красный гаолян!